# To Close, or not to Close?

Tags: discussion, closing

**Not a "My question is being closed" question**

**Quite simply: Should I vote to close?** Sometimes I come across a question that I think might be off-topic, or IMO unclear, (obviously if I don't know about the topic, I'm not going to touch it.) etc.

For example, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184060/can-xbox-one-pause-live-tv-without-a-dvr-box) had me humming and haa-ing for a while before I decided "What the hey" and voted to close as off-topic.

What's the normal practise?

Comment: "What the hey" sounds like a rather bad reason to close.

Comment: @Arperum Well, that's not *why* I closed, more the actual decision *to* close. "Voted to close as off-topic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason there are five closevotes required to close a question. Because that way, a person with a bad day going around casting closevotes all over the place can't break the site.

It also requires four other people (or a moderator) to agree with you that the question needs to be closed.

I generally end up leaving the things I'm not certain about alone, assuming that if it needs to be closed/removed/edited someone else who is more knowledgeable will step in and fix it if it is needed.

Keep doing what you think is best, if four other people agree with you that it should be closed, it'll be closed. If it ends up being impossible to find five people to agree that a question needs to be closed, the closevotes will expire and no harm is done. SO continue to do as you you, as long as you think that's the correct action to take (except when there is a clear community consensus that it should be the other way, for example: don't start casting reopen votes on every game-identification question).

Comment: I know my example is a stupid one, but couldn't think of a better one immediately.